# Page becomes unresponsive and getting 404 error in the console

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

[image]

I'm building a simple gatsby blog and somehow I'm not able to see nothing now. When I start the server, all I get is a blank page which becomes unresponsive after some time. It's like getting stuck in an infinite loop. In the console, I'm seeing this **404 page could not be found** error.

Why I'm getting a 404 error on every page? Be it the home page- `localhost:8000` or any other page like `localhost:8000/blog/react`.

Here's my `gatsby-config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: "Full-stack bootcamp",
    author: "Rick Sanchez",
  },
  plugins: [
    "gatsby-plugin-sass",
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-source-filesystem",
      options: {
        name: "src",
        path: `${__dirname}/src/`,
      },
    },
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp",
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-transformer-remark",
      options: {
        plugins: [
          "gatsby-remark-relative-images",
          {
            resolve: "gatsby-remark-images",
            options: {
              maxWidth: 750,
              linkImagesToOriginals: false,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

`/pages/index.js`

```js
import React from "react"
import Layout from "../components/layout"

const IndexPage = () => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <h1>Hello.</h1>
      <p>I'm Rick, a full-stack developer living in Seattle, Washington.</p>
      <p>
        Need a developer? <a href="www.google.com"> Contact Me</a>
      </p>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default IndexPage
```

`/components/layout.js`

```js
import React from "react"
import Header from "./header"
import Footer from "./footer"
import "../styles/index.scss"
import layoutStyles from "./layout.module.scss"

const Layout = props => {
  return (
    <div className={layoutStyles.container}>
      <div className={layoutStyles.content}>
        <Header />
        <div className={layoutStyles.text}>{props.children}</div>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Layout
```

`/components/header.js`

```js
import React from "react"
import { Link, graphql, useStaticQuery } from "gatsby"
import headerStyles from "./header.module.scss"
import linkStyles from "./layout.module.scss"

const Header = () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
      site {
        siteMetadata {
          title
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{data.site.siteMetadata.title}</h1>
      <ul className={linkStyles.list}>
        <li>
          <Link
            className={headerStyles.link}
            activeClassName={headerStyles.activeLink}
            to="/"
          >
            Home
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link
            className={headerStyles.link}
            activeClassName={headerStyles.activeLink}
            to="/about"
          >
            About
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link
            className={headerStyles.link}
            activeClassName={headerStyles.activeLink}
            to="/blog"
          >
            Blog
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link
            className={headerStyles.link}
            activeClassName={headerStyles.activeLink}
            to="/contact"
          >
            Contact
          </Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Header
```

`/components/footer.js`

```js
import React from "react"
import { graphql, useStaticQuery } from "gatsby"
// import footerStyles from "./footer.module.scss"

const Footer = () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
      site {
        siteMetadata {
          author
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  return (
    <Footer>
      Created by &copy; {data.site.siteMetadata.author}
    </Footer>
  )
}

export default Footer
```

Comment: What do you have inside `/page`  folder? What's your folder structure?

Comment: @FerranBuireu https://imgur.com/cphYhUj

Comment: Thanks! Finally, can you provide the code for `index.js`?

Comment: @FerranBuireu here's the code- https://hastebin.com/efiluxegij.js

Answer (score 1):

According to [Gatsby's documentation about 404 page](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/add-404-page/).

> Gatsby ensures that your 404 page is built as 404.html as many static
> hosting platforms default to using this as your 404 error page. If
> you’re hosting your site another way you’ll need to set up a custom
> rule to serve this file for 404 errors.
>
> When developing using gatsby develop, Gatsby uses a default 404 page
> that overrides your custom 404 page. However, you can still preview
> your 404 page by clicking “Preview custom 404 page” to verify that
> it’s working as expected. This is useful when you’re developing so
> that you can see all the available pages.

So, Gatsby needs a 404 to run, even in develop mode. Just add a `404.js` under `/pages` path, something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import Layout from '../components/layout';

const NotFoundPage = () => (
  <Layout>
    <h1>NOT FOUND</h1>
    <p>You just hit a route that doesn&#39;t exist... the sadness.</p>
  </Layout>
);

export default NotFoundPage;
```

Comment: I've added the not found page but still getting the same error.

Comment: Added as `404.js`? Cleanup cache folder.

Comment: Oh, I added the file as `404.js` now. The error in the console is gone but the behavior is still the same. Same blank page. How to clean cache folder?

Comment: Can you add in your question just the code of the `index.js`? The Pastebin is a bit confusing.

Comment: You mean the `/pages/index.js`? It's just a simple functional component. Or are you talking about the root `index.js`?

Comment: I mean `/pages/index.js`, is what Gatsby should render under `localshost:8000` so I'm trying to find out if there's an error or whatever once the console error has gone. I guess you can't see anything under`/about` too, isn't?

Comment: The last guess is to see what's inside `<Layout>` component. Can you provide it?

Comment: I've added all the components.

Comment: It's running back again after I deleted it and cloned the repo again. Thanks for the help, anyway.

Comment: In any case you can run `gatsby clean` to clear out your cache